# Query SQL In TWIG Entity and Display in twig html

Tags: sql, database, symfony, select, twig

I have a command i can produce to see the total number of referred users by referrers ID.

Really struggling to get it as a string for twig.

```
SELECT COUNT(r.`id`) AS totalReferral, r.`referrer_id` FROM `referral` r WHERE r.`status` = 'Completed' GROUP BY r.`referrer_id` ORDER BY `totalReferral` DESC
```

Current code format of my referral entity file.

```
   /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

So i can pull {{ totalreferrallist.id }} which will display the users referrals ID, but i want to be able to display a FULL list of total referrals by referrers ID as the SQL is above.

How can i insert a SQL query into a public function within my entity file?

Have tried

```
$query = SELECT COUNT(r.`id`) AS totalReferral, r.`referrer_id` FROM `referral` r WHERE r.`status` = 'Completed' GROUP BY r.`referrer_id` ORDER BY `totalReferral` DESC
```

then echo the query but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use QueryBuilder to run the query, such as this:

```
public function getTotalReferrals()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    $qb->select('COUNT(r.id) AS totalReferral, r.referrer_id')
        ->where('r.status = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', 'Completed')
        ->groupBy('r.referrer_id')
        ->orderBy('totalReferral', 'DESC');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This function returns an array of results where each result contains the referrer_id and the corresponding totalReferral count. From that loop through the results and display them in your template. e.g.

```
{% for referral in totalreferrallist %}
    Referrer ID: {{ referral.referrer_id }}
    Total Referrals: {{ referral.totalReferral }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

an alternative approach: [to demonstrate at twigfiddle](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#2cd499f620)

```
{% set referrals = [
    { 'totalReferral': 10, 'referrer_id': 1 },
    { 'totalReferral': 8, 'referrer_id': 2 },
    { 'totalReferral': 5, 'referrer_id': 3 },
    { 'totalReferral': 3, 'referrer_id': 4 },
    { 'totalReferral': 1, 'referrer_id': 5 }
] %}

{# The code above simulates the data that would be returned by the query #}

{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Referral Data</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Referrer ID</th>
                <th>Total Referral</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for referral in referrals %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ referral.referrer_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ referral.totalReferral }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have tried this but am going wrong somewhere :(

Comment: Using some made-up sample data I have attempted to demonstrate using "twigfiddle" but there's no db to run a query against there, so its emulated instead.

Answer (score 0):

to insert a sql query into a public function for your entity you need a repo function for your entity to grap the data like this

```
// src/Repository/EntityRepository.php
public function findReferralsByUser($userId): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');

    return $qb
        ->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->eq('r.userId', ':userId')
        )
        ->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->eq('r.status', ':status')
        )
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->setParameter('status', 'Completed')
        ->orderBy('totalReferral', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

you can call this function on several ways

e.g. you can create a twig extension to call it

```
// src/Twig/EntityExtension.php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use App\Repository\EntityRepository;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class EntityExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private $entityRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $entityRepository)
    {
        $this->entityRepository = $entityRepository;
    }

    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('referralsList', [$this, 'getReferralsList']),
        ];
    }

    public function getReferralsList(int $userId): string
    {
        return $this->entityRepository->findReferralsByUser($userId);
    }
}
```

and push it in twig like this

```
// templates/entity/index.html.twig
{{ set data = referralsList(user.id) }}

{% for referral in data %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have tried this but still giving me an error :(

Comment: error message ?